# Javascript IF-Else not working as expected

Tags: javascript

HI guys trying to learn javascript and been on w3schools...came across a try me that flipped the image right away from smiley.gif to landscape.jpg...so I decided I was going to see if I learned anything by flipping it with a button instead worked great...but then I decided that on each click I was going to make it go back and forth from smiley.gif to landscape and back to smiley etc...
well thats when the frustration set in..I tried a million ways other then what I originally started with down in the code section...can someone explain to me why this doesnt work..I get no console errors...It still does the initial flip from smiley to landscape on first click but then never changes back to smiley on the second click.  Thanks in Advance

```html
<img id="image" src="smiley.gif" width="160" height="120"><br>
<button onclick= myFunc() >Click</button>;

<script>
  function myFunc() {

    if (document.getElementById("image").src == "smiley.gif") {

      return document.getElementById("image").src = "landscape.jpg"

    } else {

      return document.getElementById("image").src = "smiley.gif"

    }
  };
</script>

<p>The original image was smiley.gif, but the script changed it to landscape.jpg</p>
```

Comment: In JavaScript, `=` is used to *assign*. If you're trying to check equality, you'd want to use `==` or `===`. [More info about comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison). (I'm voting to close this question as a simple typographical error.)

Comment: **Hint:** Try to understand algorithms first!

Comment: Have a read though this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: BTW I'd advise you stick with MDN as a learning resource and avoid w3schools. w3schools is notoriously bad, misleading and often downright incorrect. MDN is much more reliable. Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: Ok guys tried == and === before in the if statement instead and still does nothing..in fact it gets worse doesnt even flip images once..just frustrated makes me want to get up when I got to spend and hour on what seems to be a simple if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the `src` of the `img` when the page loads so you can compare it as the `src` gives you the full qualified path of the `img` source.

```html
<img id="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTY2gmwvcnkECDTu_N4qcfJs_5Nh1Usa8v3f-GaAzQcZxL70GpKCA" width="160" height="120"><br>
<button onclick= "myFunc()" >Click</button><br/>
<span id="result"></span>

<script>
var imgsrc = document.getElementById("image").src;
var result = document.getElementById("result");
  function myFunc() {

    if (document.getElementById("image").src == imgsrc) {
      result.innerHTML = "Image source: "+"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVQT4TyiJEFCRA3pmetp3fgZHpgQtzM1hKJMhvAJhOGchqHXQX";
      return document.getElementById("image").src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVQT4TyiJEFCRA3pmetp3fgZHpgQtzM1hKJMhvAJhOGchqHXQX"

    } else {
     result.innerHTML = "Image source: "+"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTY2gmwvcnkECDTu_N4qcfJs_5Nh1Usa8v3f-GaAzQcZxL70GpKCA";
      return document.getElementById("image").src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTY2gmwvcnkECDTu_N4qcfJs_5Nh1Usa8v3f-GaAzQcZxL70GpKCA"

    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Tyvm it  makes sense to me again....just thought it was ok becuase it would flip the first time around no problem just not back thanks again that works like a charm.

Comment: @TotalNoob No problem.

Answer (score 1):

### The Issue

An element's `src` property returns the full path to the image, including protocol.

Although you've set the attribute to `smiley.gif`, if you were to `console.log` the property value, it's something like `http://mywebsite.com/smiley.gif`. Obviously, this is *not* equal to `smiley.gif`.

**Using the `src` property:**

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("image").src);
```

```html
<img id="image" src="test.jpg">
```

In the future make sure to take these basic debugging steps. If your condition isn't working right, the first step is to verify that the values you're comparing are what you expect them to be.

---

### The Solution

Instead of using the `src` property, you want to retrieve the `src` *attribute* from the element instead. We can do this quite easily using [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

**Using the `src` attribute:**

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src"));
```

```html
<img id="image" src="test.jpg">
```

Your `if` condition should look like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src") == "smiley.gif")
```

Comment: thank you for the advice im still getting used to chromes debugger and finding it a little combersome and havent quite found how to hover over the code in the debugger and have it show me the values...but I did try and thought that I wasnt too far off since it would flip the first time. just not flip back that still doesnt make sense to me but thats life. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

compare with `==` or `===`

`=` sets the value, which is mostly true except you set a falsey value

Comment: Thanks for advice but that still doesnt work...can you show me an example of how to get this working I change the if statement to == or === then the script fails to run at all...